# How to pass options to ItemView in Marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I use Marionette and I want to pass some variables to ItemView. I tried to follow the instructions from here: http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.1/marionette.functions.html#marionettegetoption
but it's not working. My code is:

```
module.exports = function(p_hash) {
    var TreeView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template: '#tree',
        initialize: function(attributes, options) {
            if (options.type == "organizations") {
                ...
            }
        }
    });
    return new TreeView(); 
}; 
... 
var organizations_tree = new TreeView({}, {type: "organizations", two_levels: false});
```

My options are undefined in initialize method.

I probably miss something really simple.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks, Alex A.

Comment: Why do you return an instance of the view in line `return new TreeView();` ? If this module contains the view, wouldn't just `return TreeView;` be sufficient ? A possible reason why you get `options` as `undefined` is, in that `return` line `initialize` gets called, but without any parameters.

Answer (score -1):

The initialize method of a view should only take in 1 parameter.

Ex:

```
initialize: function(options) {

}
```

You're thinking of a Backbone.Model where it has 2 parameters:

```
initialize: function(attributes, options) {

}
```